# Using Optional.empty() inside catch

Tags: exception, java-8

I have an existing method in which, I have thrown `RuntimeException` by catching the `IOException`. Now as per my requirement, I'm going to change the definition as something like below.

```
try {
    // error/null producing code
    Optional.of(myModel);
}catch(IOException ex) {
    // here I removed throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    Optional.empty();
}
```

Is this a good practice or should I keep the existing method as it is?

Comment: seems very weird to ignore an `IOException`, but may be depends on your use-case

Comment: From the very little context - doesn't look like a case for Optional

Comment: I can use `orElseThrow()` in the consuming method, right?. I thought so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before `Optional`, if you invoked the `MyModel getMyModel()` method, you could get only two values:

- a `MyModel` instance, meaning everything went OK and a value was found; or
- `null`, meaning either:

  - that everything went OK but there was no value to return; or
  - that something went wrong and the method could not return a value.

Of course, for the third scenario you could always throw an exception instead of returning `null`, but sometimes that's not what you want.

`Optional` was introduced in part to better differentiate these scenarios. So now, instead of returning `MyModel`, you would declare the method as `Optional<MyModel> getMyModel()`, which meant you **could** return (warning: bad programming ahead):

- an `Optional.of(myModel)` instance, meaning everything went OK and a value was found; or
- the `Optional.empty()` instance, meaning that everything went OK but there was no value to return; or
- `null`, meaning something went wrong and the method could not return a value.

However, being that the main purpose of `Optional` was to avoid NPEs caused by methods returning `null`, it was soon found that **returning `null` from a method declared as returning `Optional` was Bad Code™**, so now the convention is to return `Optional.empty()` in the same two cases where you returned `null` before.

So **yes, returning `Optional.empty()` in the event of a caught exception is one of the expected uses of `Optional`**.
You still cannot differentiate between "no value" and "error", but at least you force the caller to take into account the possible absence of a value, and reason about what they want to do in that case: avoid any action with `ifPresent()`, take a default value with `orElseGet()`, throw an exception with `orElseThrow`, etc.

Source: *Effective Java* (3rd ed.), "Item 55: Return optionals judiciously".